# Is it possible to get StackExchange Inbox Messages send to an IM?

Tags: feature-request, support, notifications

I would like to get fast but unobtrusive notification of news on my questions or answer on the StackExchange Universe. Is there any possibility to get the Notifications send to a IM? Probably a Jabber Server to connect to?

It would just be easier than checking all the time the website.

Comment: Not really, best you can do without visiting the site is having the notifications sent to your email every 3 hours (can't more often than that). If you have server at your disposal and can write some code, you can request http://meta.stackoverflow.com/inbox/genuwine and parse it yourself, it's simple JSON data.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start. Is there any triggering mechanism around too? It would be probably not in the idea of Stackoverflow to pull all 5 seconds this JSON.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "triggering mechanism", anyhow there is live connection using web sockets that check this source and when there is change it push the red new item alert.